# unpacking / decompress winRAR file in using nifi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Can we decompress / unpack a WinRAR file using any nifi processor? I tried both unpackcontent and compresscontent but they do not have rar file format.

Comment: Probably you can use command line tool that could unpack rar format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you can take to achieve your objective:

1. You can use an `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to invoke a command-line tool like [RAR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAR) or [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).
2. You can write a Groovy/Python/Ruby/Javascript/Clojure/Lua script which uses a RAR-compatible library to perform this task and embed the script in an `ExecuteScript` or `InvokeScriptedProcessor` processor.
3. You can write a custom processor to perform this task using the [Maven NAR Archetype](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-ProcessorProjects).
4. You can open [a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/) requesting the `*.rar` type be added to the `UnpackContent` processor.

Comment: Actually the 4th sounds good, no? I think it is better to open a Jira and hopefully someone will take a look.